# Issue getting viewState's selected child's id in flex 4

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex3, viewstack

I'm transitioning a flex 3 application to flex 4.  There was AS code in the flex 3 app that worked:

```
var myCurrentSelectedChild:String = myViewStack.selectedChild.id;
```

Now, in flash builder and flex 4.5, it throws the error - "-1119: Access of possibly undefined property id through a reference with static type mx.core:INavigatorContent".  I'm trying to get the viewStack's selected child's id.

Comment: try to cast the myViewStack.selectedChild to some displayObject type. core:INavigatorContent has no ID property.    So use (myViewStack.selectedChild as DisplayObject).id

Comment: @TiMeister DisplayObject doesn't have ID property but Container does so used (myViewStack.selectedChild as Container).id and it works.  Thanks

Comment: Sorry I wanted to type UIComponent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to cast the myViewStack.selectedChild to some UI Object type. 
core:INavigatorContent has no ID property.

So use:

```
(myViewStack.selectedChild as Container).id
```

Answer (score 1):

The following links may be helpful:

- http://jksnu.blogspot.com/2011/06/view-state-difference-between-flex3-and.html
- http://jksnu.blogspot.com/2011/06/view-state-difference-between-flex3-and_24.html

Answer (score 0):

```
var myCurrentSelectedChild:String = myViewStack.selectedChild.getChildAt(0).id;
```

Comment: selectedChild doesn't have getChildAt method